# htaccess to allow 1 unique url/link at a time access a page

Tags: security, .htaccess

I am using S2member plugin within wordpress to generate access to PPV content (sporting event video).  This is set up as single page access after payment. When the user clicks to purchase, it takes them to paypal and then after payment redirects them back to the restricted page with a unique url string something.com/?s2member_sp_access=635v545d52504p4i4q5v645n5c3j313e5f3c3u493t3d3h3d323d5e4a3t3v3a3c3737373b49483m3h3j313e5f3c3u493n3d

Now my problem is that though each user that buys gets a unique url string, they can copy it and send to others and give access to the content to anyone else they want without paying.

I would like to close this loophole, by having something in place that will allow only one unique url (string) access to the page at the same time. Therefore even if they give the url away, only one person could get in at the same time, there ending multiple users on for free.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately there is not much you can do about users who wish to redistribute the content. Even if you make the URL single-use, the customer can still download it once and copy it for other people themselves. To counteract that you might consider using a watermark to make the content unique per customer so that you can at least know which customer redistributed the content if you find copies in the wild.

That being said, your question as asked does not make sense. You say "allow only one unique url (string) access to the page at the same time" but urls (strings) do not access web pages, user agents do!

There are at least two things you can do to make it harder for customers to redistribute the URL for downloading the content and perhaps foil casual attempts to redistribute. Both require you to run some code (a script, etc...) upon URL access to they are not configuration you will put in `.htaccess` per se.

- Make the URL single-use.

  Whenever the unique URL is accessed, check a database that marks whether or not each unique URL has been used before. If it has not been used before, mark it used. If it has been used before, deny the request.

  **Pro**: easy

  **Con**: *very* annoying for users whose download breaks or is interrupted. They can't retry!
- Use a cookie to make the URL work only in one browser.

  Whenever the unique URL is accessed, check if the user agent supplied a cookie with a certain name. If not, this may be the first access to this URL. Check your database to see if the cookie should have already been set for this unique URL. If yes, then deny the request. If no, then choose a new random value for this cookie and set it in your database and return it with the response. If the user agent *did* present a cookie, check its value against your database to make sure it is correct and allow the request only if yes.

  **Pro**: one customer can access the URL an unlimited number of times from one browser

  **Con**: a smart user could copy the cookie value from their browser and publish it so that other people can set it manually in their browsers and thwart your protection scheme.